# why python need to open file every time when we use the data?

Tags: python, function, built-in

The code below have two same lines, but I think fr is already opened by the first line. I try to remove the second lines, but the code failed. So why we need to the open file everytime when we use it?

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename) #<-------------------------
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())
    returnMat = np.zeros((numberOfLines,3))
    classLabelVector = []
    fr = open(filename) # <------------------------
    index = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(listFromLine[-1])
        index += 1
    return returnMat, classLabelVector
```

Comment: Why do you need the number of lines? You don't appear to be doing anything with that information...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reopen the file, but you do need to go back to the beginning.

The readline() function reads a line in a file. Each time you call readline(), the pointer will move to the next line.

readlines() calls readline() until it gets to the end of the file. If you want to move back to the beginning, you need to reopen the file. (Generally, it's better practice to actually close and then reopen the file. Even if you're only reading once, you should close the file at the end.)

If you only want to go through the file once, you can count the number of lines as you move through the file, and then return that number.

Original:

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())
    returnMat = np.zeros((numberOfLines,3))
    classLabelVector = []
    fr = open(filename)
    index = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(listFromLine[-1])
        index += 1
    return returnMat, classLabelVector
```

Another way:

```
def file2matrix(filename):

    fr = open(filename)

    classLabelVector = []

    index = 0
    line = ''
    numberOfLines = 0

    while line is not None:

        numberOfLines += 1

        line = fr.readline()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')

        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(listFromLine[-1])

        index += 1

    fr.close()

    returnMat = np.zeros((numberOfLines,3))
    return returnMat, classLabelVector
```

Comment: In your *other way*, ```returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]``` at this line what is ```returnMat```?  And why do you why do you assign something different to it after you apparently just filled it up?

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure what the OP was trying to do, so I wanted to give both options for returnMat.

Comment: @wwii, returnMat[index, :] = listFromLine[0:3], this line is just for nature of my dataset, no use for other program. My dataset is in txt format, each line contain 3 feature data and the final one is label, that's why I assign to it. And zeros in former are just for initializing the returnMat, like variable definition